# Get count on several fields using mongoose aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in my MongoDB `employee` and `employeeData` i need to get some statics information from DB.

1. total employees who were not deleted.
2. total employees who have security access and are not deleted.
3. total employees still active;

this is my `Employee` collection sample document

```
{
 _id:'5ec25e74d028af28343f1061'
 isDeleted:false
 securityAccess:true
 details:'60475b7a93ac45d64a5957b0'
}
```

this is `EmployeeData` collection document

```
{
  _id:'60475b7a93ac45d64a5957b0'
  emplyeeId:'5ec25e74d028af28343f1061'
  isActive:'active',
  salary:225543.00,
  department:'sales'
}
```

I need to get this data from one query using some kind of aggregations but I'm not much familiar with the MongoDB queries.

the expected result looks like this.

```
Total Employees | Active Employees | Security Access
         10            5                    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` to check `isDeleted` condition
- `$lookup` with `EmployeeData`
- `$group` by null

  - get total employees count,
  - count total security access if `securityAccess` is true
  - count total active employees if `isActive` is 'active'

```
db.Employee.aggregate([
  { $match: { isDeleted: false } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "EmployeeData",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "emplyeeId",
      as: "activeEmployees"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalEmployees: { $sum: 1 },
      securityAccess: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: ["$securityAccess", 1, 0]
        }
      },
      activeEmployees: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: [{ $first: "$activeEmployees.isActive" }, "active"] },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3jvfWh0Aov6)

Comment: @turvishal i made one mistake here in my EmployeeData `isActive` is a string not boolean.its either `active` or `inActive`.  i change the query like this `$cond: [{ isActive:['$eq','Active']}, 1, 0]` but it didn't work.update my question sorry for the inconvenience.